# Fire and forget with TPL

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have following code:

```
public void Func()
{
   ...
   var task = httpClient.PostAsync(...);

   var onlyOnRanToCompletionTask = task
            .ContinueWith(
                t => OnPostAsyncSuccess(t, notification, provider, account.Name),
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

   var onlyOnFaultedTask = task
            .ContinueWith(
                t => OnPostAsyncAggregateException(t, notification.EntityId),
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

   return true;
}
```

Func is not async and I would like to have something like fire and forget but with continuation function. I don't want to have that function async. The scenario is that this function is called in some kind of loop for group of objects to handle them. For me the problem seems that e.g. onlyOnRanToCompletionTask can be deleted when we finish Func execution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "fire and forget but with continuation"? And "this function is called in some kind of loop for group of objects to handle them"? Can you please think through what you're asking and try to make it clearer?

Comment: Ok so let me explain it in a better way. There is a code which calls this Func in a loop. The Func tries to get some entry from DB and if there is anything to handle it tries to send async post. I don't won't to wait till post is finished but would like to allow for next run of Func. The problem is that when the post is finished we would like to change the status of previously gathered entry. Is that clear now?

Comment: It is not recommended, but you can make it async void.  It executes async and is not awaitable, and thus, fire & forget.

Answer (score 1):

But your code should be performed as expected. Simple example:

```
void Main()
{
    HandlingMyFuncAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Doing some work, while 'fire and forget job is performed");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public void HandlingMyFuncAsync()
{
    var task = MyFuncAsync();
    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}

public async Task<string> MyFuncAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    return "A";
}
```

produces

> Doing some work, while 'fire and forget job is performed
>
> [end after 5 sec]
>
> A

Comment: Isn't it an issue that your task can be deleted by GC (maybe not in this simple example but generally)? This is local variable and how can we be sure that it won't deleted like something to which we don't have references. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Deff No the original task acts as a root for GC, so the continuation will not get collected until after the task finishes.

Comment: @Deff - Tasks don't get collected until they complete. I think that's part of the TPL's contract for running tasks.

Comment: @Enigmativity do you have some url to documentation/msdn doc which says that?

Comment: @Deff - It's actually because the thread pool references the thread that the task is running on - so until the thread completes the task can't be GC'ed.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd look at using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx) for this. Rx is designed for this kind of thing.

Here's some basic code:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] source = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };

    IObservable<int> query =
        from s in source.ToObservable()
        from u in Observable.Start(() => Func(s))
        select s;

    IDisposable subscription =
        query
            .Subscribe(
                x => Console.WriteLine($"!{x}!"),
                () => Console.WriteLine("Done."));
}

public void Func(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"+{x} ");
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
    Console.WriteLine($" {x}-");
}
```

When I run that I get this kind of output:

```
+1 
+2 
+3 
 1-
!1!
 2-
!2!
 3-
!3!
Done.
```

It triggers off all of the calls and waits for the results to come in. It also let's you know when it is done.

Here's a more practical example showing how to use async and Rx to return a result:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] source = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };

    var query =
        from s in source.ToObservable()
        from u in Observable.FromAsync(() => Func(s))
        select new { s, u };

    IDisposable subscription =
        query
            .Subscribe(
                x => Console.WriteLine($"!{x.s},{x.u}!"),
                () => Console.WriteLine("Done."));
}

public async Task<int> Func(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"+{x} ");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
    Console.WriteLine($" {x}-");
    return 10 * x;
}
```

That gives:

```
+1 
+2 
+3 
 1-
!1,10!
 3-
 2-
!2,20!
!3,30!
Done.
```

Without seeing your full code I can't easily give you a complete example that you can use, but Rx will also handle opening an closing on your DB contexts using the `Observable.Using` operator.

You can get Rx by Nugetting "System.Reactive".